# How extract Values from List with Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I requested a JSON File from API. Then I want to parse/save just some values out of the File.

**Code:**

First the request call:

```
request = requests.get(self.url, verify = False)
request_data = request.json()
```

Example File (Type <class 'list'>):

```
[
    {
        "id1": null,
        "id2": "test1",
        "id3": "test2",
    }
    {
        "id1": null,
        "id2": "test3",
        "id3": "test4",
    }
]
```

Now I just want to get all id2 and their value, I tried with the code below, but it only works with dictionaries, how can I convert the list to a dictionary? Or can I extract the values with a list too?

```
value = {}
output_data = {}
value["id2"] = data.get("id2")
output_data.append(value)
```

Comment: `output_data.append()`?, it is a dict.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA ah yes you are right, it should be output_data = [ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of dictionaries. One Pythonic way of dealing with this would be:

```py
all_id2s = [entry['id2'] for entry in request_data]
```

This would create an array containing just the `"id2"` elements, like:

```py
['test1', 'test3']
```

Check it out on IDEOne: https://ideone.com/5iVZhw

Comment: Great, it works. Thank you!
But it says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" if i pass the request_data as an input argument of a function like this -> def parse(data): all_id2s = [entry['id2'] for entry in data] -> parse(request_data)

Comment: @TomTom, in that case, it sounds like your data type is different. Perhaps you have an array within an array? Could you do a `print(repr(request_data))` where you currently have `parse(request_data)`? That will hopefully clarify the data structure.

Comment: The output is [[
    {
        "id1": null,
        "id2": "test1",
        "id3": "test2",
    }
    {
        "id1": null,
        "id2": "test3",
        "id3": "test4",
    }
]], so there are 2 [[ ]]

Comment: @TomTom, gotcha, so then you would need to call `parse` like: `parse(request_data[0])`.

Comment: Thank you very much, perfect !! :) @Spencer-d

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below:

```
var = [
    {
        "id1": "null",
        "id2": "test1",
        "id3": "test2",
    },
    {
        "id1": "",
        "id2": "test3",
        "id3": "test4",
    }
]
output = []
for i in var:
    output.append(i['id2'])

print(output)
```